# CakePHP add action returning json

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have some questions on how I can improve this "add action" (method) in "controller":

**1st:** I'm using the `add` action only if post request. It's correct ?

**2nd:** This `action` doesn't have views (`$this->autoRender = false;`). It's correct ?

**3rd:** I set a response .json file to this `action` but I didn't change on routes to routing .json files (the file will be return when access **localhost:8765/users/add**). It's correct ?

**4th:** I'm using `Enums`(handmade) to store messages that will returned to user. It's correct ?

**5th:** I'm using an object to store the fields of message (that will returned to user), that object will be serialized and returned like this:

```
$this->response->body(json_encode($response)); // It's correct ?
```

**Controller code:**

```
public function add()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->response->type('json');
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user->toArray());
            $response = new ResponseMessage();
            $response->code = CodeEnum::USER_ADDED;
            $response->name = NameEnum::USER_ADDED;
            $response->type = TypeMessageEnum::SUCCESS;
            $this->response->body(json_encode($response));
        } else {
            $response = new ResponseMessage();
            $response->code = CodeEnum::USER_NOT_ADDED;
            $response->name = NameEnum::USER_NOT_ADDED;
            $response->type = TypeMessageEnum::ERROR;
            $this->response->body(json_encode($response));
        }
    }
}
```

[UPDATE]

I put this on my controller:

```
$this->set('response', $response); 
$this->set('_serialize', ['response']);
```

but return this json:

```
   {response: {code: 1, name: "Login efetuado com sucesso.", message: null, type: "Sucesso"}}
```

but must be returned only:

```
{code: 1, name: "Login efetuado com sucesso.", message: null, type: "Sucesso"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1st: I'm using the add action only if post request. It's correct ?

Yes

> 2nd: This action doesn't have views ($this->autoRender = false;). It's correct ?

Not really. Instead of setting json string to response body in controller you should use [JsonView](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) which does the job for you.

> 3rd: I set a response .json file to this action but I didn't change on routes to routing .json files (the file will be return when access localhost:8765/users/add). It's correct ?

That's fine. Using URL ending in not .json is not necessary. But you should set `Accept` header in request to `application/json`.

> 4th: I'm using Enums(handmade) to store messages that will returned to user. It's correct ?

That's fine. You could check out this [enum](https://github.com/cakedc/enum) plugin.

> 5th: I'm using an object to store the fields of message (that will returned to user), that object will be serialized and returned like this:

As stated above better to use JsonView.

Comment: I update my answer with correct code and the new problem.

Comment: Change `$this->set('_serialize', ['response']); ` to `$this->set('_serialize', 'response'); `